# Printing an array such that the values can be copied and pasted to a Excel Row

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, interoperability, excel, clipboard

Given an array I would like to print it in *Mathematica* such that the **values** can be simply copied and pasted into an Excel's row. What is the best approach for this?

```
data = Array[0, 32];
For[k = 1, k < 100, k++,
  i = RandomInteger[{1, 32}];

   data[[i]] = data[[i]] + 1;

  ];

data
```

output:

```
{5 + 0[1], 4 + 0[2], 4 + 0[3], 3 + 0[4], 1 + 0[5], 1 + 0[6], 1 + 0[7],
  5 + 0[8], 3 + 0[9], 0[10], 3 + 0[11], 2 + 0[12], 4 + 0[13], 
 4 + 0[14], 2 + 0[15], 5 + 0[16], 1 + 0[17], 4 + 0[18], 2 + 0[19], 
 1 + 0[20], 4 + 0[21], 2 + 0[22], 2 + 0[23], 2 + 0[24], 4 + 0[25], 
 2 + 0[26], 4 + 0[27], 4 + 0[28], 4 + 0[29], 8 + 0[30], 4 + 0[31], 
 4 + 0[32]}
```

Comment: `data = Array[a, {5, 5}]; Export["exportedData.xls", data // Flatten];`  Then open `exportedData.xls` in `Excel`

Comment: @BobHanlon, thank, but I needed a way to display the Array in the Notebook in a Excel copy and paste friendly  format.

Comment: `data // Flatten // Column` select data then `Copy As` `Plain Text`. Select cell in `Excel` and `Paste`

Comment: @BobHanlon, that displays something {
 {3 + 0[1]},
 {5 + 0[2]},
 {12 + 0[3]},
 {24 + 0[4]},
 {44 + 0[5]},
 {101 + 0[6]},
 {163 + 0[7]},
 {260 + 0[8]}
} 

How can I make it display JUST the values, and not the Array indexes.

Comment: @BobHanlon I have updated the question with the mathematica code that i am using.

Comment: What about something like `TableView[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]`

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon. That worked! :) If you make at an answer, I will mark it as accepted. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 10;

data = ConstantArray[0, n];
```

Note use of [`ConstantArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConstantArray.html) rather than [`Array`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html)

```
For[k = 1, k < 100, k++, i = RandomInteger[{1, n}];
  data[[i]] += 1;];
```

Note use of [`AddTo (+=)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AddTo.html)

```
data // Column
```

[image]

Select column in workbook then `Copy As` `Plain Text`. Select cell in `Excel` and `Paste`

Comment: Doesn't work on scientific notation.

Comment: @Quarkly - No it doesn't, but it did what the OP wanted and he told me to convert the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to print the data as a `"TSV"` string in a separate `Cell`:

```
data = RandomReal[1, 10];
CellPrint@Cell[ExportString[{data}, "TSV"], "Print", TextClipboardType -> "PlainText"]
```

> ```
> 0.25961013187287674   0.12283879171332623 0.41817318423675176 0.7052661059327268  0.2174563190189165  0.5695344741754753  0.2714439130949191  0.4690459007786689  0.641512306420351   0.2207889610686835
> ```

Then you can select the row by double-clicking, copy and paste into an Excel sheet:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: `CopyToClipboard@ExportString[data, "TSV"]` is nice too.  (and works better I think with a 2d matrix )